# How can I increase dissolved nitrogen in flowing water?

Tags: water

Will injecting pure nitrogen gas using a diffusion stone increase the dissolved nitrogen content in water while the water is flowing through a pipe?

Comment: Yes it should. Look up Henry's law.

Comment: If it's already saturated, no.